# Generate python/php/c#/go/c++/java structures by JS/JSON object

Tags: javascript, npm, data-structures

I need a reverse from JSON.stringify function for node.js. I need to generate code snippets for different programming languages and need to convert JS structure to python/php/other languages native structures.

Source example: `{"a": 5, "b": true, "c": null}`

Target example (python): `{"a": 5, "b": True, "c": None}`

Target example (php): `array("a" => 5, "b" => true, "c" => null)`

Is there any easy way to do this, instead of inventing my own code generator?

Comment: Seems like you'd end up inventing the one.
Don't think there is anything available as it is very specific task without many reasonable applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partially solved this issue:

1. `kong/httpsnippet` module had generation of PHP structure
2. Python:
   `child_process.execSync('python -c 'import sys,pprint,json; pprint.pprint(json.loads("\n".join(sys.stdin.readlines())))', {input: "{"a": 5, "c": ["b", null]}"})`
3. Ruby:
   `echo '{"a": null}' | ruby -rjson -e 'puts(JSON.parse(ARGF.read).inspect)'`

Now I need Java and C#